# Form is not getting submitted in Angular 8

Tags: angular, iframe, angular-reactive-forms

I am submitting a form from code when my cookie is available. But form is not getting submitted. Please see the code. The same code is working in Angular 7.

A few changes that I have done is @ViewChild new syntax. Please see the code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="frmRender" [formGroup]="ssrsFromGroup" #frmRender [action]="ssrsReportUrl" method="post" target="embedFrame" (ngSubmit)="submitForm();">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="rs:Command" value="Render">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="rs:Embed" value="true">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="rc:LinkTarget" value="main">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="rs:Format" value="HTML4.0">

</form>

<iframe [hidden]="!cookiePresent" title="SSRS" class="ssrs-height" id="embedFrame" name="embedFrame" [src]="ssrsReportUrl" fxFlexFill></iframe>
```

**Component code**

```
    @ViewChild('frmRender', { static: false }) frmRenderEl: ElementRef;
    ssrsFromGroup = new FormGroup({});
```

**Inside ngOnInit() or AfterViewInit()**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.params.ssrsReportName = 'PatientsReviewReport';
    this.ssrsUrl = '';

    this.ssrsReportUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.ssrsUrl);
    this.generateCookie();

  }


private generateCookie() {
    this.service.iFramePathService(this.params).pipe(first()).subscribe((response) => {
      this.ssrsUrl = response.ssrsEmbeddedUrl;
      this.ssrsReportUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.ssrsUrl);
      console.log('this.frmRenderEl', this.frmRenderEl);
      this.frmRenderEl.nativeElement.submit();
      this.setCookies(response.cookieValue);
      this.cookiePresent = true;
    }, (error) => {
      // this.showError(error.error);
      console.log('There is an error generating cookie for SSRS and showing it.', error);
    });
  }


 public submitForm() {
    console.log('Form is submitting automatically.');
  }
```

The code where I have mentioned

```
this.frmRenderEl.nativeElement.submit();
```

[image]

is getting failed and it is not calling submit() method. The same code with older Viewchild in Angular 7 is working fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your code here:

```
<form id="frmRender" [formGroup]="ssrsFromGroup" #frmRender [action]="ssrsReportUrl" method="post" target="embedFrame" (ngSubmit)="submitForm();">
```

You'll see that `(ngSubmit)="submitForm();"`. That's what you are looking for. It expects a function named `submitForm` in your .ts file.

```
 submitForm() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    // your logic here
  }
```

**Edit:**

> Question is how can I submit form from my other generateCookie function.

Change it to: `(ngSubmit)="generateCookie()"`

**Edit 2:**

Since you want to execute generateCookie on ngOnInit(), you should remove this line from there:

```
this.frmRenderEl.nativeElement.submit();
```

submitForm() is supposed to be executed right after you press the submit button in your form. It makes no sense to submit the form once the page loads for the user, I mean literally.

2nd way:
In my opinion, it's better to generate the cookie once you submit the form.

```
submitForm() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    // Generate your cookie
    this.service.iFramePathService(this.params).pipe(first()).subscribe((response) => {
      this.ssrsUrl = response.ssrsEmbeddedUrl;
      this.ssrsReportUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.ssrsUrl);
      this.setCookies(response.cookieValue);
      this.cookiePresent = true;

      // Cookie is generated, so you can process further

    }, (error) => {
      // this.showError(error.error);
      console.log('There is an error generating cookie for SSRS and showing it.', error);
    });
}
```

Note `Cookie is generated` comment. That's basically the time when the cookie is generated and after that line you can do the rest of your logic.

**Edit 3:**
Okay, I got it, you want to trigger the form from outside.

```
@ViewChild('frmRender') frmRender: FormGroupDirective;
```

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" id="ngForm" #frmRender="ngForm">
...
</form>
```

You can trigger the form by doing this:

```
this.frmRender.ngSubmit.emit();
```

Comment: It is not working. I forgot to add in my question. I updated my question.

Comment: I want to execute the code generate cookie via nOnInitMethod() and then I want to submit my form. That's my requirement.

Comment: `ngOnInit` executes in the beginning and you have your function called there `generateCookie()`. It makes no sense to submit the form on page load. The question is when do you want to generate the cookie in the beginning or when you submit the form.

Comment: I want to generate the cookie first. Once I have the response. Then I want to submit the form from component code. This is what I am doing in generateCookie method.

Comment: Hi, thank for edit answer. The requirement is, there is no visible button to click on HTML for submitting the form. It should get called automaically after I am getting my cookie. Getting cookie and submitting the form are two different things here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit answer. There is no button to submit the form. I want to do it manually once I have my generated cookie. Generated cookie I am getting in ngOnInit(). From there I want to submit the form from my code itself. As this code was working in Angular 7, I think it might be related to ViewChild Line.??

Comment: I see, I got your point. You wanted to trigger the form submit from outside, basically. Edited it again.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Edit 3 worked. I was assigning it to ElementRef instead of FormGroupDirective during ViewChild code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aksah you have to make onSubmit method in your ts file

```
   onSubmit() {
      // write your logic here
   }
```

Comment: ngSubmit() method which is mentioned in HTML file is already there in .ts file. Or should I change it to onSubmit in both HTML and TS file?

Comment: ya make onSubmit method in ts file and change the method name in html file also

Comment: What error? ngSubmit's function name must match to the one in your .ts file.

Comment: I have updated my question with all the proper lines and one screenshot attached.

Comment: make the function name same and , ithink the problem is in your viewchild make you form viewchild like that: @ViewChild('frmRender ', { read: NgForm }) form: any;

Comment: I have tried that. Once I update the @ViewChild like you mentioned, it gives me error, "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" at my generateCookie method submit line

Answer (score 0):

```
(ngSubmit)="submitForm();
```

this bit of code is for submitting your form, you need a submitForm() function in your .ts file and have the logic inside that function.

Comment: It is present already in my .ts file. If you see my HTML file. Question is how can I submit form from my other generateCookie function.

Comment: I dont know why you want to submit your form straight after drawing it, but if you set 
@ViewChild('frmRender', { static: true}) frmRenderEl: ElementRef; if would be there before ngOnInIt call

Comment: I am not submitting it straight after. I am submitting it in my generateCookie service call. Once I have that, I am attaching that response URL to iFrame in HTML. As the response is related to SSRS report, it requires a reload or submit of the form